# How can I solve the equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{e^y - t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following equation?

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{e^y - t}$$

I feel as if I am missing something obvious with this question but have been trying to figure it out for too long now. The only hint given is to try and treat $y$ as the dependent variable, however I don’t understand what that means for me to do.

Comment: The hint is asking you to rewrite this differential equation in terms of $\frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d} y}$, which can be interpreted as the derivative of $t$ as a function of $y$. All you need to do is reciprocate both sides, and you should be left with a first order linear equation in terms of $t = t(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$y'(e^y-t)=1$$
Rewrite it as:
$$t'=e^y-t$$
$$t'+t=e^y$$
Where $t'=\dfrac {dt}{dy}$. And solve.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is dependent on $t$, then we're treating $t$ as a function of $y$ (i.e. $t = t(y)$), and it makes more sense for you to find $\frac{dt}{dy}$.

$\frac{dt}{dy} = \frac{1}{dy/dt} = \frac{1}{1/(e^y - t)} = e^y - t$

And it should be much easier to solve from that point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find an integrating factor, and *remember the product rule*.

Before we do that, let's get this into a bit of a nicer form.

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{e^y - t} \\
e^y\,dy - t\,dy = dt \\
$$

Now, the tough term is $-t\,dy$ because it mixes variables.  However, the product rule can help with mixed variables.  However, it needs two parts to work, and one of them needs to be with $dt$.  So, we will move this term over to be on the same side as $dt$.

$$ e^y\,dy = dt + t\,dy $$

Now, the right-hand side is *almost* in a form that will work for the product rule.  Remember, the product rule is $d(jk) = k\,dj + j\,dk$.  However, there is not a function of $y$ next to the $dt$.  However, if you multiply by $e^y$, then, since $e^y$ is both the value and the derivative, it can work in both settings.  Therefore, multiplying the whole equation by $e^y$ gives you:

$$ e^y\cdot e^y\,dy = e^y\,dt + e^y\,t\,dy \\
e^{2y}\,dy = e^y\,dt + e^y\,t\,dy 
$$
The product rule tells us that the right-hand side is merely the differential of $t\,dy$.  Therefore, we can rewrite the equation as
$$ e^{2y}\,dy = d(t\,e^y) $$.
This is then very easy to integrate:
$$ \int e^{2y}\,dy = \int d(t\,e^y) \\
\frac{1}{2}e^{2y} = t\,e^y + C
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac1{e^y-t}$

$\big(e^y-t\big)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$

$e^y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-t\dfrac{dy}{dt}-1=0$

$2e^{2y}\dfrac{dy}{dt}-2te^y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-2e^y=0$

$\dfrac d{dt}\left(e^{2y}-2te^y\right)=0$

$e^{2y}-2te^y=c\;,\quad$ where $\;c\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

$e^y=t\pm\sqrt{t^2+c}$

$y(t)=\ln\left(t\pm\sqrt{t^2+c}\right)\;.$